# getting runtime error when accessing node through the queue

Tags: binary-tree

i am trying to connect the nodes of a binary tree that are at the same level
i am using a queue to do it. initially i have pushed the root into queue. but in line 12 when the first if statement is executed that is 
if(q.front()->left!=NULL) then i am getting a runtime error. 
please help

**node structure:**

```
struct node
{
    int data;
    struct node* left;
    struct node* right;
    struct node* nextRight;
};
```

**function to connect the nodes**

```
node* connect(node* root)
{
    if(root=NULL)
        return display(root);
    queue<node*> q;
    int count=0;
    q.push(root);
    count++;
    while(!q.empty())
    {
        cout << "inside while loop\n";
        int i=1,temp=0;
        while(i<=count)
        {
            cout << "inside inner while\n";
            if(q.front()->left!=NULL)
            {
                cout << "inside if 1\n";
                q.push(q.front()->left);
                temp++;
            }
            if(q.front()->right!=NULL)
            {
                cout << "inside if 2\n";
                q.push(q.front()->right);
                temp++;
            }
            node* v=q.front();
            q.pop();
            if(i==count)
                v->nextRight=NULL;
            else
                v->nextRight=q.front();
        }
        count=temp;
    }
    return display(root);
}
```

Comment: what is that runtime error?

Comment: segmentation fault

Answer (score 0):

You need to make lot of changes in your code.

Mistake 1:

```
while(i<=count)
```

will never be true.

Mistake 2:

```
v->nextRight=q.front();
```

will set the nextRight to point to Left child.

Mistake 3:

`i` is never changing, then why declare a variable and create confusion.

Comment: thank you i have made the changes and now it's working